# How to re-route a website to different hosting platforms

Tags: dns, hosting

Can I host a website with two hosting providers? For example. Can I have (www.example.com)domain with ABC host and XYZ host. Just to re route during traffic

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Yes, you can. But that's not what you actually want to know, I'm sure. So you should ask what you actually want to know and do it on the proper site.

Comment: @sami-kuhmonen What i want is....I have a website that seems to have traffic but I need to reduce the traffic on that host. Maybe, host on another hosting provider and then reroute each user....i hope you understand this